# Creating a django project in eclipse on win7?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I have installed python and django on win 7. Both works and runs fine in the command line. I proved it with `import django` and then getting the version `print django.get_version()`. After that step I installed pydev from the update page in eclipse. I autoconfigured the python path in the preferenc window. However, when I create a python project I get:

[image]

Here you can see that an "empty" project was created. However I looked into two variables which should be defined:

**DJANGO_MANAGE_LOCATION** and **A DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**

However I get:

[image]

Therefore my question is:

How to set the manage.py to get the django structure when creating a new django project?

**UPDATE**

OK guys I figured out the solution:

1. create a project in pydev
2. create a project with django
3. the pydev and the django project should have the same name
4. copy the project into the eclipse workspace and press F5
5. have fun;)

Comment: You should install PyDev http://www.pydev.org. Once you installed it you can create a new Django project in Eclipse. This post http://lowcoupling.com/post/47845431628/creating-a-new-django-project-with-eclipse-py-dev provides a complete tutorial for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this yesterday, and ran in to the same problem.  I had to run `django-admin.py startproject [projectname]` from the command line in the project workspace directory to get all the files autogenerated.  After you do that, it is pretty self-evident what you need to set the project configuration to (a manage.py and settings.py file will be generated in the project directory, and you just provide a relative path to manage.py and a package path to settings in the appropriate project configuration fields).